# How to create custom cell without using reuse Identifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am making a program in which I am fetching a image from URL and displaying on the custom cell and rest of the table data on other cells.

Here is the code:

```
image=[[UIImage alloc]init];

if(indexPath.row==0)
{

    LabelTableViewCell *cell=[detailtable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imagecell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    NSOperationQueue *myqueue=[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    NSBlockOperation *downloadOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
        [cell.actindi startAnimating];
        image=[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[frontimage objectAtIndex:0]]]];

    }];
    downloadOperation.completionBlock=^{
        cell.imageprimary.image=image;
    [cell.actindi stopAnimating];

    };
    [myqueue addOperation:downloadOperation];


        return cell;
    }
else
{
        LabelTableViewCell *cell = [detailtable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tabledetail" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.labelspec.text=[firstArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.txtfield.text=[secondArray1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
return 0;
```

Problem I am facing:

1. Whenever I scroll up it reloads the top cell.
2. It dont reload the image on first cell till I click on that cell.
3. `if(!cell)` and `if (cell==nil)` not working.
4. Reloading the table puts in an infinite loop till I scroll down.

So I want to permanently allocate the memory to the first cell as it is only one in number.

I have tried putting nil in dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier and its not working.

I have gone about 20-30 articles to do that but nothing has worked for me I don't know why.

So please give me any specific solution at the present condition.
I am new in the iOS developing don't know too much about it . This is my first program that I am trying to make.

Comment: try to change LabelTableViewCell *cell=[detailtable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"imagecell" forIndexPath:indexPath]; with this: NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imagecell%d",indexPath];     LabelTableViewCell *cell=[detailtable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:string];

Comment: Cells didn't loaded even after doing this...

Comment: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'

Answer (score 1):

You can try it different way:

To download and show image Just use library - https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Library will download image and cache for you.

Comment: I am not willing to use any library because I want to learn the things at present.

Comment: You will have to build your own cache then. It should be owned by the table view.

Comment: You will have to build your own cache then. It should be owned by the table view.